# Performance drop after upgrading Catel to 4.4.0

Tags: wpf, catel

I have problem with performance on newest Catel release. I was previously using `4.2.0-unstable0127` and now trying to upgrade to `4.4.0`

Most probably, the problem is with Catel's TabControl.

I have following code (which switches tab very fast on 4.2.0):

```
<catel:TabControl
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            BorderThickness="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Screens}"
            LoadTabItems="EagerLoading"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveView}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="interfaces:IScreenModule">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{Binding Presenter}"
                        DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </catel:TabControl>
```

My IScreenModule is a class with Presenter and ViewModel created in constructor.

With this code, changing tabs was not handling all of the initialization/deinitialization of Catel stuff.

After upgrading to `4.4.0` changing tabs lost a lot of performance. It's registering/unregistering views on tab change etc.

Were there any change in Catel, which I did not noticed? Or it's broken there?

Comment: I am not aware of any changes in the TabControl. Can you please try 4.5 prerelease, it contains a lot of performance improvements. If you still feel it's slow, create a repro so we can test it.

Comment: I have updated Catel to newest version (4.5 prerelease) - Same problem here. 
Then I have tried to just create my own TabControl based on source from 4.2.0 - Working.

So the problem must be somewhere between `4.2.0` and `4.4.0`

Comment: Thanks for the research. Please create a Jira ticket so we can research & fix this.